# jQuery <select> option enable just some options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How do I choose which one selector/option I want to disable/enable while selecting one of options at other selectors

For example:

I would like to have them all disabled except for "unit_block", after I choose one of the option (A or B) "unit_row_big" will enable allowing me to chose any of the options, but "unit_row" will enable only some of the options.

Basically here is spreadsheet how I would like to create it.

I have everythink working basically, but it is not bulletproof.

How you can see in block A (upper one) there are 4 bigger cells (unit_row_big) wile block B have 3 of them. Then some bigger cells in block B have 12 smaller cells (unit_row) but all of them have 5 smaller cells wide (unit_column). For example if I would like to create Large (unit_size) cell on 2-5th position it would collide with next big cell so I would like to have exception that size Large can be used only when unit_column is 1 Medium if unit_column is 1 or 5 and Small every time.

I found few examples of disabling/enabling option in selectors but none this particular. Since I'm pretty bad with javascripts I have no idea how to create one, and I feel good if I can at least edit one.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MkY8Bt_HuaRAvd7J_4R1BohEEyI1qkNBTMZgTllmlFA/edit)

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ae3jqmd/)

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_block" id="unit_block" >
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_row_big" id="unit_row_big" disable>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_row" id="unit_row">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_column" id="unit_column">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_size" id="unit_size">                
    <option>Small</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>Large</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery but this is pretty easy in pure JavaScript.

You just need to monitor whatever selectors you want and then make the `disabled` attribute `true` based on those choices. I made a small fiddle where if `B` is selected in the first dropdown, `2` is disabled on the second dropdown. You should be able to easily expand on that.

[image: Disabled option based on other dropdown.]

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/6no3jyzb/

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  'use strict';

  var unitBlock = document.querySelector('select#unit_block');
  var unitRowBig = document.querySelector('select#unit_row_big');

  unitBlock.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (unitBlock.value === 'B') {
      // [1] is equal to option '2'
      unitRowBig[1].disabled = true;
    } else {
      unitRowBig[1].disabled = false;
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<form class="form-signin" method="post" id="register-form">

  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Unit specification</h2>
  <hr />

  <div id="error">
    <!-- error will be showen here ! -->
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_name" id="unit_name" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_group" id="unit_group" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_block" id="unit_block">
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_row_big" id="unit_row_big">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_row" id="unit_row">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_column" id="unit_column">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker" name="unit_size" id="unit_size">
      <option>Small</option>
      <option>Medium</option>
      <option>Large</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <hr />

  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-save" id="btn-submit">Insert</button>
  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: I see that your code is working, however in my final solution it's not affect the options 

http://testmm.hys.cz/log/add_unit.php

I made it public, so if you can help me one final time and tell me what am I doing wrong.

Script you told me to use is under add_select.js

Thank you

Comment: That code was only a starting point. You aren't using `select` elements in your markup, but rather `button`'s with a dropdown. You should switch those over to using `select` and `option` elements.

Comment: As I once said, I'm preety bad with these so I come down to use https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ to save my work, as I look once more at his page he have some kind of methods there but I have no idea what his code mean, can you tell me if there is possible way how to make it work using these, otherwise I have no idea how to make it as nice and as quick

Comment: You already have the `select` tags in there, just remove the `button` tags: https://clbin.com/LcesNn.png

Comment: one more thing please?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217368/javascript-multiple-functions-at-once