# javascript multiple functions at once

Tags: javascript, html

As I needed help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211413/jquery-select-option-enable-just-some-options)

@ryanpcmcquen offered great help, but as a "noob" at javascript I would like to know 2 more things

When I want to create another function how do I make it?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  'use strict';

  var unitBlock = document.querySelector('select#unit_block');
  var unitRowBig = document.querySelector('select#unit_row_big');
  var unitRow = document.querySelector('select#unit_row');
  var unitColumn = document.querySelector('select#unit_column');
  var unitSize = document.querySelector('select#unit_size');

  unitBlock.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (unitBlock.value === 'A') {
      unitRowBig.disabled = false;
      unitRowBig[4].disabled = false;
    } else {
      unitRowBig.disabled = false;
      unitRowBig[4].disabled = true;
    }
  });


  unitBlock.addEventListener('change1', function () {
    if ((unitRowBig.value === '1') && (unitBlock.value === 'A')) {
      unitRow.disabled = false;
      unitRow[8].disabled = true;
      unitRow[9].disabled = true;
      unitRow[10].disabled = true;
      unitRow[11].disabled = true;
      unitRow[12].disabled = true;
    }
  });


});
```

Because it doesn't seems to work my way.

Comment: What kind of event is `change1` ? And what you have in `unitBlock`?

Comment: it would be long piece of text, best look at previous example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211413/jquery-select-option-enable-just-some-options

Comment: `change` is a [DOM event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) but `change1` is nothing if you didn't define it. Pls explain "create another function". Do you mean another `<select>` object?

Comment: i figure out that change is event by now, but other problems popped out, read down bellow please

Answer (score 0):

No need to add a new event, besides `change1` is not a valid event, you can find a list of events here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Just put that conditional inside the original event handler:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  'use strict';

  var unitBlock = document.querySelector('select#unit_block');
  var unitRowBig = document.querySelector('select#unit_row_big');
  var unitRow = document.querySelector('select#unit_row');
  var unitColumn = document.querySelector('select#unit_column');
  var unitSize = document.querySelector('select#unit_size');

  unitBlock.addEventListener('change', function () {

    // You may want to comment out all of this section:
    if (unitBlock.value === 'A') {
      unitRowBig.disabled = false;
      unitRowBig[4].disabled = false;
    } else {
      unitRowBig.disabled = false;
      unitRowBig[4].disabled = true;
    }
    // Down to here.

    // Here's your code!
    if ((unitRowBig.value === '1') && (unitBlock.value === 'A')) {
      unitRow.disabled = false;
      unitRow[8].disabled = true;
      unitRow[9].disabled = true;
      unitRow[10].disabled = true;
      unitRow[11].disabled = true;
      unitRow[12].disabled = true;
    // Including an antithetical clause,
    // to account for the user changing their mind.
    } else {
      unitRow.disabled = true;
      unitRow[8].disabled = false;
      unitRow[9].disabled = false;
      unitRow[10].disabled = false;
      unitRow[11].disabled = false;
      unitRow[12].disabled = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Note that I also included the opposite `disabled` conditions in an `else` clause, in case the user makes one choice, and then changes to another.

Comment: Thanks man, you are my savior, but there is one mistake and that is if you select A, then select 1 in next column you have to re-select A in order to execute that condition, live demo here http://testmm.hys.cz/log/add_unit.php

Comment: @Tahak probably related to disabling all of `unitRowBig`. Let me make an edit you can try.

Comment: I see what you did there, but I was planning to add planty off code to this all of it some kind of if disable/enable so if I comment that upper thing and add more it willl be the same :(

Comment: Yes, sorry, it did worked out kinda, as I mention to @Pierre Tassel as you can see here: http://testmm.hys.cz/log/add_unit.php If I pick block A and then unit row big 4 it chose option I have for 2 || 3 as you can see here http://testmm.hys.cz/log/add_select.js not talking about problem if you pick A, then choose one of the numbers, switch to B it did not correct them as I need them on B, I have to switch to A and back to B for javascript to take action

Comment: @Tahak you could try something like this: https://www.irccloud.com/pastebin/t8l6SJfi/add_select.js

Comment: This doesn't really do anything, A 4 is still thinking that you are choosing A 2 || 3 and I'm not able to slowly enable things as user go trought. Btw. this A 4 thing I cannot undestand how is this happening and why it is choosing A 2/3 over and over again, demo stil at the same place

Answer (score 0):

In case you really need two separate functions (what is not the case here), just do it like this:

```
unitBlock.addEventListener('change', function () {
   console.log('First event listener')
});


unitBlock.addEventListener('change', function () {
    console.log('Second event listener')
});
```

`document.addEventListener` stores all the functions you sent to him, so when the change event will be fired, it will execute all of them, in the order you passed them to it.

In short, when the change event is fired, you will have:

```
> "First event listener"
> "Second event listener"
```

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Thanks, I did manage to get this work, kind off, how you can see here: http://testmm.hys.cz/log/add_unit.php If I pick block A and then unit row big 4 it chose option I have for 2 || 3 as you can see here http://testmm.hys.cz/log/add_select.js